# A presentation of group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I am trying to verify that the so-called Heisenberg group over the finite field ${\mathbb{F}}_p$ of order $p$ (with order $p^3$ and exponent $p$) has the following presentation:
$$
G = \langle x, y ~:~ x^p, y^p, [y,x,y], [y,x,x] \rangle 
$$
given in a paper (Ref. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00605-016-0938-5 Page-687, Thm.4.3)

On a different look, it seems like that the commutator $[y,x]$ in $G$ is central and is of infinite order. Shouldn't we add another relation $[y,x]^p$ here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that presentation is correct.

Since $x$ commutes with $[x,y]$, we have $[x,y]^p = [x^p,y] = 1$.

This follows from the standard commutator identities, which you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The relation you pointed out follows from the standard power-commutator collection formula (Ref. Prop.1.1.32, Leedham-Green, McKay, The structure of groups of prime power order). I should have used this earlier.